# How to control merge button with Github Actions?

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

What I want to do is simple:

1. The merge button can only be released if the actions executed in pull_request (opening, reopening, editing) pass all jobs correctly.
2. After managing to merge, deploy to vercel must be executed.

Two problems occur:

1. Even running the workflows when opening the PR, it is possible to merge while it runs or even when it gives an error.
2. When the PR is merged and closed, the deploy workflow for vercel gives a "skipped" status and doesn't even run.

**WORKFLOW_CONTROLLER**

```
name: WORKFLOW CONTROLLER

on: [workflow_dispatch, pull_request]

jobs:
  frontend:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/frontend-test.yml
  backend:
    needs: frontend
    uses: ./.github/workflows/backend-test.yml
```

**VERCEL DEPLOY**

```
name: VERCEL DEPLOY

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed

jobs:
  vercel-deploy:
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && github.event.pull_request.merged == true }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]
        architecture: [x64]
    steps:
      - name: Check out Git Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: RUN DEPLOY [VERCEL]
        uses: amondnet/vercel-actions@v20
        with:
          vercel-args: '--prod'
          vercel-token: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
          vercel-org-id: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_ORG_ID }}
          vercel-project-id: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_PROJECT_ID }}
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a branch protection rule to enforce certain workflows for the branch, such as requiring an approving review or **passing status checks** for all pull requests merged into the protected branch.

To do that, navigate to your Repository *Settings*, click *Branches*, and then *Add Rule*. There is an option '*Require status checks to pass before merging*' which allows choosing which status checks must pass before branches can be merged.

For more details see [Creating a branch protection rule](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/managing-a-branch-protection-rule#creating-a-branch-protection-rule).

Regarding the second question, try the following:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
    types: [ closed ]

jobs:
  vercel-deploy:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true

    ...
```

Reference: [Trigger workflow only on pull request MERGE](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26724)